# Sorting optimization for date

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

```
I have been sorting a collection like this. i was wondering whether it can be optimized or not. please have a look:

//ordering elements i.e latest ToDate will be on top and if ToDate are same then latest FromDate will be in top
var posistions = (someModel.Positions.OrderByDescending(x => x.ToDate)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.FromDate).Where(x => !x.ToDate.HasValue).ToArray())
    .Concat(someModel.Positions.OrderByDescending(x => x.FromDate)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.ToDate).Where(x => x.ToDate.HasValue).ToArray());

someModel.Positions = posistions.ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating the lists? is that to say, if Todate doesn't have a value, 
then they should come last, however sorted by fromDate?

Comment: First i thought, as i am ordering ToDate by descend, if there is no ToDate, it will move to the block written after concat. you guessed it right

Comment: First optimization would be to not chain 10 LINQ commands together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just do something like this. I am not sure what polarity you need from the ordering however its easily changed

```
var positions = model.Positions
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.ToDate.HasValue)
                     .ThenByDescending(x => x.ToDate)
                     .ThenByDescending(x => x.FromDate);

foreach (var pos in positions)
   Console.WriteLine(pos.ToDate+" : " + pos.FromDate);
```

**Output**

```
8/8/2018 5:34:49 AM : 8/8/2018 5:34:49 AM
8/7/2018 5:34:49 AM : 7/2/2018 5:34:49 AM
8/6/2018 5:34:49 AM : 6/22/2018 5:34:49 AM
null : 8/1/2018 5:34:49 AM
null : 7/22/2018 5:34:49 AM
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7MJRe)

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nNbT5D

a small adjustment to the accepted answer:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.ToDate ?? DateTime.MinValue)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.FromDate);
```

this code is enough to replicate the result.

see the result using this sorting criteria

```
From: 8/4/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 
From: 7/25/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 
From: 6/25/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/9/2018 7:35:00 AM
From: 7/5/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/10/2018 7:35:00 AM
From: 8/11/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/11/2018 7:35:00 AM

 result using question's sorting criteria below
From: 8/4/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 
From: 7/25/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 
From: 8/11/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/11/2018 7:35:00 AM
From: 7/5/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/10/2018 7:35:00 AM
From: 6/25/2018 7:35:00 AM ========= ToDate: 8/9/2018 7:35:00 AM
```